# SSL Certificate Issue with Certbot & Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, certbot

I'm having some issues with the SSL certificate of a wordpress site built on digitalocean.
the domain is [www.23hoops.io](http://www.23hoops.io). I'm working with Apache

I do not have much experience with, so I'd really appreciate some help

Comment: *"I'm having some issues"* - this is not a usable error description. There seems to be a problem that your site redirects to https://167.71.66.74/ for some unknown reason - and the certificate there is invalid. It is unclear though why your site is doing this since absolutely nothing is known about the setup. And this has likely nothing to do with certbot at all.

Comment: I'm actually checking if there's some missconfiguration with Wordpress, I built a droplet with DigitalOcean Wordpress (https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/wordpress) Once I did the setup I didnt had the domain so probably the issues comes from there

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Digitial Ocean publishes very good tutorials. Search for one.